# R summarize many to many relationship between two column's value in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns. I am interested in two columns. There is many to many relationship between the values of these two columns.
Example:

```
df = data.frame("A"=c(1,1,2,3,4,1,2),"B"=c("a","b","a","c","s","b","s"))
> df
A B
1 a
1 b
2 a
3 c
4 s
6 b
7 a
```

Now the result would be

```
a -> 1,2,7
b -> 1,6
c- > 3
s -> 4
```

Also, I want to save then as R object as list. So next time I can directly access them like, if I say them as RObject and if I type RObject$a, that should give me list of 1,2,7, etc.

Updated:
It works fine for above exmaple, but when I tried on following example:

```
head(gf[,c(3,5)])
         V3         V5
  DNAJC25-GNG10 GO:0004871
  DNAJC25-GNG10 GO:0005834
  DNAJC25-GNG10 GO:0007186
  LOC100509620 GO:0005215
  LOC100509620 GO:0006810
  LOC100509620 GO:0016021
```

Some how it converts the V3 columns in numbers?
It gives

```
   V5   V3
 GO:0004871 4283
 GO:0005215 8796
```

Comment: How did you get those values? Your `df` doesn't look like that.

Comment: Your example does not match the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split` which should be very fast.

```
split(df$A, df$B)
#$a
#[1] 1 2 7

#$b
#[1] 1 6

#$c
#[1] 3

#$s
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unstack(df)
#$a
#[1] 1 2 7
#
#$b
#[1] 1 6
#
#$c
#[1] 3
#
#$s
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
aggregate(data = df,.~B,FUN = paste,collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that save the results in a named list:

```
temp <- aggregate(A~B, df, FUN=c)
myList <- setNames(temp$A, temp$B)

myList
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 1 1

$c
[1] 3

$s
[1] 4 2
```

**data**

```
df = data.frame("A"=c(1,1,2,3,4,1,2),"B"=c("a","b","a","c","s","b","s"))
```